# How to solve this elliptic integral ??

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Can anyone explain to me how to find the integral ?

$$ \int_0^1\sqrt{9x^4+4x^2+1}dx =? $$

Comment: Ask Wolfram Alpha and then reverse-engineer the method that led to the answer.

Comment: If you check WA brace yourself for a tough experience, as the solution involves elliptic integrals of the first *and* second kind, plus inverse hyperbolic functions of complex arguments and other kinds of terrible...terrible stuff. May the force be with you!

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Texts on elliptic integrals from 100 years ago show how to convert any such thing into the standard forms.  (I have a reprint of such a text on my shelf.)  But nowadays very few people need to do that themselves.

Comment: @GEdgar Could you suggest such a text, because I am interested in learning how to compute elliptic integrals  in a structured way and don't know where to start, apart from Wikipedia.

Answer (score 4):

A text:

Harris Hancock, *Lectures on the Theory of Elliptic Functions*, 498 pages (1909)

I have the Dover edition,  1958

I looked in Amazon ... it seems the soft cover edition is now selling for around \$10, and the Kindle edition is \$1 ...

Comment: I will look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

$$\underbrace{\int\sqrt{9x^4+4x^2+1}\ dx}_J=x\sqrt{9x^4+4x^2+1}-\int x\frac{\big(9x^4+4x^2+1\big)'}{2\sqrt{9x^4+4x^2+1}}dx=x\sqrt{f(x)}-I.$$

$$x\cdot f'(x)=4\Big[f(x)-(2x^2+1)\Big]\iff I=2\ J-4\underbrace{\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{f(x)}}dx}_{I_2}-2\underbrace{\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{f(x)}}}_{I_2}$$

$J=\dfrac{x\sqrt{f(x)}+4\ I_1+2\ I_2}3$ . For both integrals, let first $t=x^2$, then complete the square in their denominator, and use the fact that $\text{arcsin[h]}'u=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1\mp u^2}}$, with $u=u(t)$, in order to **finally** be able to express them in terms of [elliptic integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) of $y(u)=w\big(\text{arcsin[h] }u\big)$.

Comment: waht do you mean by $y(u)=w\big(\text{arcsin[h] }u\big)$

Comment: The final expression, in terms of *x*, after all intermediary variables have been recursively replaced in terms of the previous ones, will yield something like a combination of elliptic integrals of (hyperbolic and/or trigonometric) arcsines of a radical of a rational function of *x*.

Answer (score 1):

Although this integral really belongs to an elliptic integral, but this does not means we can always express an elliptic integral to the elliptic integral of the three standard types conveniently, http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=%289x%5E4%2B4x%5E2%2B1%29%5E%281%2F2%29&random=false can tell us why.

Besides, it is better to tackle this integral to this series approach:

Hint:

$\int_0^1\sqrt{9x^4+4x^2+1}~dx$

$=\int_0^\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{13}-2}}{3}\sqrt{9x^4+4x^2+1}~dx+\int_\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{13}-2}}{3}^1\sqrt{9x^4+4x^2+1}~dx$ (separation according to the root between $0$ and $1$ of $9x^4+4x^2=1$)

$=\int_0^\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{13}-2}}{3}\sqrt{1+x^2(9x^2+4)}~dx+\int_\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{13}-2}}{3}^1x\sqrt{9x^2+4}\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{x^2(9x^2+4)}}~dx$

$=\int_0^\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{13}-2}}{3}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!(x^2(9x^2+4))^n}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)}dx+\int_\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{13}-2}}{3}^1x\sqrt{9x^2+4}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)(x^2(9x^2+4))^n}dx$

$=\int_0^\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{13}-2}}{3}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!C_k^n4^{n-k}9^kx^{2n+2k}}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)}dx+\int_\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{13}-2}}{3}^1x\sqrt{9x^2+4}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)x^{2n}(9x^2+4)^n}dx$

$=\int_0^\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{13}-2}}{3}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!9^kx^{2n+2k}}{4^kn!k!(n-k)!(1-2n)}dx+\int_\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{13}-2}}{3}^1\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)x^{2n-1}(9x^2+4)^{n-\frac{1}{2}}}dx$